# Pegar dados de WebService em Action do C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-service, soap

Tenho uma aplicação que acessa WebService de terceiros. Para melhorar o processo de testes, estou montando um site para simular o WebService.

Este site consiste em diversos Actions, que retornam o XML, simulando dados. Esta parte está **ok**.

O meu problema é que não estou conseguindo pegar os parametros de entrada, que vem do meu aplicativo.

Lembrando que o meu aplicativo continua com a mesma estrutura para enviar os dados para o WebService, porém somente com a URL apontando para o meu site.

Tentei usar Request no controller, e não consegui pegar os dados.

#### Referencia gerada pelo C# ao importar o WSDL

```
[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapRpcMethodAttribute("", RequestNamespace="http://services.teste.com.br", ResponseNamespace="http://services.teste.com.br", Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal)]
[return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("result")]
public moedasExportarOut Exportar(string user, string password, int encryption, moedasExportarIn parameters) {
    object[] results = this.Invoke("Exportar", new object[] {
                user,
                password,
                encryption,
                parameters});
    return ((moedasExportarOut)(results[0]));
}
```

#### Action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult XML(string user, string password, int? encryption, string methodName,
    Moeda.moedasExportarIn parameters, 
    Moeda.moedasExportarIn arg, int? codEmpField)
{
    XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
    var teste = "";
    teste =
        "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> " +
        "<S:Envelope xmlns:S=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"> " +
        "   <S:Body>" +
        "       <ns2:ExportarResponse xmlns:ns2=\"http://services.teste.com.br\">" +
        "           <result>" +
        "               <erroExecucao xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:nil=\"true\"/>" +
        "               <finalizaramRegistros>S</finalizaramRegistros>" +
        "               <mensagemRetorno xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:nil=\"true\"/>" +
        "               <numLot>0</numLot>" +
        "               <tipoRetorno>1</tipoRetorno>" +
        "           </result>" +
        "       </ns2:ExportarResponse>" +
        "   </S:Body>" +
        "</S:Envelope>";

    xd.LoadXml(teste);
    return new XmlResult(xd);
}
```

#### Chamada do WebService, feito pelo meu aplicativo

```
public Teste.Moedas.moedasExportarOut ExportarMoeda(DadosParaIntegracao dados, Teste.Moedas.moedasExportarIn parameters)
{
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = conexaoSimultaneaPorServico;
    var service = new Teste.Moedas.g5services();
    service.Url = dados.Configuracao.URL;
    service.Timeout = ConfiguarTimeOut(service, dados.Configuracao);
    ConfigurarProxy(service, dados.Proxy);

    try
    {
        ConfigurarIntegracao(service);
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
        return service.Exportar(dados.Login.Login, dados.Login.Senha, 0, parameters);
    }
    finally
    {
        LimparIntegracao();
    }
}
```

Não consegui nem pegar o valor de user, password ou qualquer outro parametro.

Comment: Como você está fazendo para chamar a *Action*?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez adicionei a forma que é chamado o WebService

Comment: Não o *Web Service*. A *Action*.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez A Action simula o retorno do WebService. Em vez da minha URL apontar para o WebService, aponta para a minha Action e envia os mesmo dados se estive-se enviado os dados para o WebService. No codigo acima estava Controller é na verdade a minha Action. Já ajustei.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez alguma ideia de como fazer?

Comment: Confesso que ainda não entendi como funciona a cadeia de chamadas. Em teoria, `XML` chamada `ExportarMoeda`, que chama o *WebService* é isso mesmo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pelo que eu pesquisei, o termo correto do que eu queria era **mock**, que é algo para simular um WebService. O meu problema estava em pegar o que o meu cliente de WebServer manda para o servidor. Pesquisando na internet achei isto:

```
var parametros = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
```

No `Request.InputStream` tinha todas a solicitação. Então adicionei outras funcionalidades, e consegui ler os dados enviados, e responder um XML e sinular o WebService.

Valeu a ajuda pessoal.

Meu fonte completo ficou:

```
public class WSController : Controller
{

    private string RetornaPorta(string parametros)
    {
        try
        {
            var xml = new Regex("<soap:Body>(.*)</soap:Body>").Split(parametros)[1];
            return xml.Split(' ')[0].Substring(1);
        }
        catch
        {
            return "Erro na porta";
        }
    }

    private string RetornaChave(string parametros, ServicoWS servico)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(servico.Chave))
        {
            return "";
        }

        var retorno = "";
        foreach (var item in servico.Chave.Split(';'))
        {
            try
            {
                var valor = new Regex(String.Format("<{0}>(.*)</{0}>", item)).Split(parametros)[1];
                retorno += item + "=" + valor + ";";
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
        return retorno.Substring(0, retorno.Length - 1);
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public ActionResult ConfirmarResposta()
    {
        var parametros = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
        var servico = new ServicoWS();

        using (var db = new Conexao())
        {
            servico = db.ServicoWS.BuscaTipoEPorta("ConfirmarResposta", RetornaPorta(parametros));
            var chave = RetornaChave(parametros, servico);

            var xml = db.ServicoWSRetorno.Where(w =>
                w.ServicoWSID == servico.ServicoWSID &&
                w.Chave == chave).FirstOrDefault();

            XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
            xd.LoadXml(xml.Retorno);
            return new XmlResult(xd);
        }
    }
}
```